# Why is $X\cap A=A\cap X=A$, not $X\cap A=A\cap X=X$ for the operation $\cap$ on $\mathcal B(X)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Sets and Groups by Green an Example 79 reads:

"Example 79. The subsets $X,\emptyset$ of a given set $X$ are the unit and zero elements, respectively, for the operation $\cap$ on $\mathcal B(X)$. For $X\cap A=A\cap X=A$, and $\emptyset\cap A=A\cap \emptyset=\emptyset$, for all subsets $A$ of $X$. For the operation $\cup$, these roles are reversed; X is zero and $\emptyset$ the unit operator."

I do not see how $X\cap A=A\cap X=A$, but I can see how $\emptyset\cap A=A\cap \emptyset=\emptyset$. My thinking is:

Take $X=\{x,y,z\}$. Then $\mathcal B(X)$ has eight elements $\emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\}, \{z\}, \{x,y\}, \{x,z\}, \{y,z\}, \{x,y,z\}$. These eight elements can be part of the set A such that $A=\mathcal B(X)$. Now $X\cap A=A\cap X=X$. What I'm missing?

Comment: A is one of the subsets, it's ain't the power set of X..

Comment: Ah, that would make sense ..., but then how would it work for "the operation $\cup$, these roles are reversed; $X$ is zero and $\emptyset$ the unit operator"?

Comment: It would work, its Just a not-clear way to explain that doing the $\cup$ operation of one of the subsets with the origin set will bring you the origin one...

Comment: For reverse roles I'm getting $A\cup X=X\cup A=X$ which does means $X$ isn't a zero operator. But $A\cup \emptyset=\emptyset \cup A=A$ works and $\emptyset$ becomes a unit operator.

Comment: Yeah, that's about right

Comment: But the example states that for the reverse roles X becomes a zero operator, hence I expect get something like $X\cup A = \emptyset$.

Comment: It means that like when you multiple something and zero you get zero, then if you $\cup$ set ($X$ ) with one of his subset you will get $X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For $X\cap A=A\cap X=A$, and $\emptyset\cap A=A\cap \emptyset=\emptyset$, for all subsets $A$ of $X$.

$A=\mathcal B(X)\implies A\not\subset X$.

Comment: OK, $A=\mathcal B(X)\implies A\not\subset X$. But $A=\mathcal B(X)\implies X\subset A$. So $X\cap A = X$, not $X\cap A = A$, right?

Comment: Yes, so $X$ would be the subset (as opposed to $A$) which also verifies the statement. The gist is that $\text{set}\cap\text{subset}=\text{subset}\cap\text{set}=\text{subset}$.

Comment: It's still confusing, because (1) if X is the subset then $X\cap A = X$, but example states that it's $X\cap A = A$ and (2) the example also states "all subsets $A$ of $X$; I guess that implies that $A$ is a subset.

Comment: Yes, the example states $$\underbrace{X}_{\text{set}}\cap\underbrace{A}_{\text{subset}}=\underbrace{A}_{\text{subset}}$$ because *it assumes that $A$ is the subset*! When $X$ is the subset (of $A$), you have $$\underbrace{A}_{\text{set}}\cap\underbrace{X}_{\text{subset}}=\underbrace{X}_{\text{subset}}\cap\underbrace{A}_{\text{set}}=\underbrace{X}_{\text{subset}}$$ and the roles are reversed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so A is some subset of the power set. Not the power set itself. But then your statement in the answer is incorrect, right?
$A=\mathcal B(X)\implies A\not\subset X$

Comment: I was pointing out the fallacy in your example with $A=\mathcal B(X)$ and $X=\{x,y,z\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a subset of $X$, so $A$ in an element of $\mathcal{B}(X)$ but it cannot be all of $\mathcal{B}(X)$, because $\mathcal{B}(X) \not\subset X$. However if you start with the set $\mathcal{B}(X)$ and take the subset $X \subset \mathcal{B}(X)$, then $X \cap \mathcal{B}(X)=\mathcal{B}(X) \cap X=X$, but here you changed the set.